# "Crushing complement of open $n$-ball in an (compact) $n$-manifold to a point" is homeomorphic to $S^n$

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

Let $M$ be an (compact?) $n$-manifold with $x\in M$. Then we have an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $U$ is homeomorphic to an open $n$-ball $B$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. be I am trying to prove the following:

> $M/(M\setminus U)\cong S^n$.

I understand $D^n/\partial D^n\cong S^n$, and supposedly this is useful here, but I don't see how.

Comment: You are given a homeomorphism $f: B \to U$, where $B$ is an open ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$. For the result you want, you need to extend $f$ to the closure $\overline{B}$ of $B$ in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and then you will be able to use the result that $D^n/\partial D^n \cong \overline{B}/(\overline{B} \setminus  B)$ is homeomorphic to $S^n$. If $M$ is compact, then you can extend $f$ to $\overline{B}$ by considering sequences that converge to points on $\overline{B} \setminus B$. The result is not true, in general, if $M$ is not compact, e.g., take $M$ to be an open ball in $\Bbb{R}^n$ and take $U = M$.

Comment: @RobArthan: I am not sure how to extend $f$. Attempting to try to define an extension $F\colon\overline{B}\to U$; for $x\in\overline{B}\setminus B$ there is a sequence $x_n$ in $B$ such that $x_n\to x$. By continuity of $f$, $f(x_n)\to f(x)$ where $f(x_n)$ is a sequence in $U$.  So, I guess now we used that $M$ is a compact manifold to get $f(x)$ is in $U$? But I'm not sure how.

Comment: The extension maps $\overline{B}$ to $\overline{U}$ (a closed subset of the compact manifold $M$ and hence a compact set).

Comment: You might first try to prove that if $\overline U$ is a compact neighborhood of $x$ homeomorphic to a closed $n$-ball, then $M/(M \setminus \text{int}(U)) \cong S^n$, then weaken to homeomorphism requirement to then interior and the open ball, and finally back out to the full result.

Comment: Even if $M$ is compact, $\overline{U}$ need not be a closed ball, which makes this somewhat tricky to prove (in particular you will need to use the local topology at points of $\partial U$). Maybe it's enough to shrink $U$ to a smaller ball around $x$ so that you know $\overline{U}$ is homeomorphic to a closed ball?